# Slash appears at the cursor insertion point when keyboard shortcut is used

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ctrl, capslock, reformatting

I switched “Caps Lock key” and “Control key” using System Settings…->Customise modifier keys->modifier keys

When I do Command + Ctrl + L  (now Command + Option + L ) to execute “Reformat Code” the file is reformatted, but as soon as I press any key a slash (/) appears at the cursor insertion point. How can I prevent this unwanted insertion?